# sortable How can I put back element to the previous position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I understand how to get the order, but I dont know how to put the element back to previous position before action when its necessary.

Please advice, Thank you very much.

```
el.sortable({
    start: function(){   var order = etc //Got current order here//  },

    update: function(){
         //Process and etc//

         if(cancel) {
            //how can I put the element back to the position before??
         }

    },


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$( ".selector" ).sortable( "cancel") will work (AFTER you initialized your sortable, of course, **not INSIDE** the initialization)

```
el.sortable({
    start: function(){   var order = etc //Got current order here//  },

    update: function(){
         //Process and etc//

         if(cancel) { //NO NOT HERE
            //how can I put the element back to the position before??
         }

    },


});

el.sortable("cancel"); //here
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel

> cancel()
>
> Cancels a change in the current sortable and reverts it to the state
>   prior to when the current sort was started. Useful in the stop and
>   receive callback functions. This method does not accept any arguments.